# IFTTT + Maker URL trigger not firing

Tags: ifttt

I'm having some trouble getting the Maker applet to work properly in IFTTT. I've created a recipe and tried to fire it with ***https://maker.ifttt.com/trigger/EVENTID/with/key/SECRETKEY*** and I see ***Congratulations! You've fired the ####### event*** in the GET reply (I've also tried POST, which works too), but the event doesn't actually happen. How can I tell the event doesn't happen?

1. The IFTTT recipe that uses a Maker URL trigger to control a SmarterThings Outlet doesn't actually turn on the SmarterThings device... I wish there was an IFTTT way to click a button in the web UI and say, "run this recipe *as if* the Maker URL had just triggered." Perhaps that exists?
2. From what I hear the incoming Maker trigger should show up in ifttt.com/logs (or ifttt.com/activity ) and it does not. Presumably this knowledge eliminates the SmarterThings Applet as the problem and indicates that my fundamental issues is a problem getting the Maker trigger to work.

Can anyone help me out? I'm an IFTTT noob and I've scoured their site and tried submitting a support ticket but I'm not getting a reply.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It turns out my problem was using eventID instead of eventNAME in the URL. The necessary token is the name you created for your event, as opposed to the automatically generated unique id.

Also notable is that the "event fired" message is only an indicator that you have (1) a well formed URL and (2) a valid secret_key. So that's useful, but it does not confirm you've actually fired an event that exists.

Comment: Thanks for posting! You can accept your own answer now to help others and get a badge.